# Print the 2 most common consecutive occurrences of a substring in a string and how often they occur

Tags: python, string, loops

So I'm working on a project where I look at certain sport teams records and want to see the most and second most occurred "streak" of a certain  result, or lack thereof (ie most consumers winless streak), I tried to write some basic code but it doesn't work properly like I want to and as such gives the wrong answer and the wrong count.

This is the code I tried:`your text`

```
played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"

streak = 0
max1 = 0
max2 = 0
repeat1  = 1
repeat2 = 1
savemax1 = 0
savemax2 = 0
for i in played:
    if  i == "W":
        streak=streak+1
        print(streak)
    else:
        if streak >= max1 and streak >= max2:
               if streak > max1 and streak > max2:
                   max2 = max1
                   max1 = streak
                   streak = 0
               elif streak > max2 and streak < max1:
                   max2 = streak
                   streak = 0
               elif streak == max1: 
                   if max1 == savemax1:               
                       repeat1 = repeat1+1
                       streak =0
                   else:
                       savemax1 = max1
                       repeat1 = 1                      
                       streak = 0
               elif streak == max2:
                   if max2 == savemax2:
                       repeat2 = repeat2+1
                       streak = 0
                   else:
                       savemax2 = max2
                       repeat2 = 1
                       streak = 0
        else:
              streak = 0

print(str(max1) + " has occured " + str(repeat1) + " time(s)")  
print(str(max2) + " has occured " + str(repeat2) + " time(s)")
```

this returns:
5 has occured 2 time(s)

3 has occured 1 time(s)

it should return:
5 has occured 3 time(s)
4 has occured 1 time(s)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? 

-What defines a streak? (Two or more of the same outcome? Three or more of the same outcome?)
-Is a winning, losing, or draw streak all grouped into the same streak count? Or does a winning streak occurrence have a separate count from a losing streak occurrence?

Comment: @MichaelMezher in theory anything, streak is just what I used to name the var for myself, but essentially the highest (and second highest) number of consecutive occurrences of a substring so in this case "W", "D" or "L" (which i change manually within the code right now) so if the string would be something like WDWDLWDLWDW then the highest outcome of all of those would only be 1

Answer (score 1):

If counting winning streaks, (W), you could use regular expression and collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
import re

played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"

c = Counter(map(len, re.findall('W+', played)))
for key in sorted(c, reverse=True)[:2]:
    print(f'length {key} occured {c[key]} time(s)')
```

Prints:

```
length 5 occurred 3 time(s)
length 4 occurred 1 time(s)
```

For the longest winless streak

```
from collections import Counter
import re

played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"

c = Counter(map(len, re.findall('[LD]+', played)))
for key in sorted(c, reverse=True)[:2]:
    print(f'length {key} occured {c[key]} time(s)')
```

Prints:

```
length 12 occured 3 time(s)
length 11 occured 1 time(s)
```

Comment: if you wanted to do this for say a winless streak, so like consecutive games of draws or losses, how would you need to change this?

Comment: @Kevin Mattsson I've updated my reply for the 2 longest winless streaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to read and debug, here a an implementation that works for you.

```py
played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"


def func(win_loose: str):
    longuest = 0
    longuest_time = 0
    second_longuest = 0
    second_longuest_time = 0
    current = 0
    for score in win_loose + "L":
        if score == "W":
            current += 1
            continue
        if current > longuest:
            longuest, second_longuest = current, longuest
            longuest_time, second_longuest_time = 1, longuest_time
        elif current == longuest:
            longuest_time += 1
        elif current > second_longuest:
            second_longuest = current
            second_longuest_time = 1
        elif current == second_longuest:
            second_longuest_time += 1
        current = 0
    return longuest, longuest_time, second_longuest, second_longuest_time


max_1, repeat_1, max_2, repeat_2 = func(played)
print(str(max_1) + " has occured " + str(repeat_1) + " time(s)")
# 5 has occured 3 time(s)
print(str(max_2) + " has occured " + str(repeat_2) + " time(s)")
# 4 has occured 1 time(s)
```

Comment: Yeah I know I basically tried to write some "simple" code without too many vars and functions and dug myself into a hole, this works though so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `re`, using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"

lds = Counter(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(played, lambda ch: ch in 'LD') if k)
for k, g in lds.most_common()[:2]:
    print(f'Length {k} occured {g} time(s)')
```

Prints:

```
Length 1 occured 29 time(s)
Length 2 occured 23 time(s)
```

---

If you want only wins:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

played = "LLWLDLLLDLWLLLLDLLDLLLWLLLWLWWLWDLWLLLWDLDLDDDLLWDLDWWLDLDLDLLDDLLWWLDWLLWWLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLWWWDLDDLLWLDWDLLDLLDDDDLLWDDLLWWLWDLLLLLWWLLDLLDLDWDLDLDWDLDDLLWDDLWWWLWDDDWLDLDWDDDLLWDWWLWDLDLWWWDDLLLLWLDWWWWWLWLWWDDDLWWWDLDLLLLLLDWWWWWDLWWLWWDDLDWDLWWDWWLLWWWLLWDWDLDDWDDDWLWWLLLLDWLDWWDLWDWWWWLLDLWLLWWWWWLDLDWWLLLWWDLLDLDLLLWLLDDLLDDDWLWLWLLWLDDWLLLLLDLLWWDWDWLDLLLWDLLWWLWWLLWLLLLDWLWWLLDWLLDDDDLLLLWDWDLWLLLDLDWDDDLLWLDLLWWLWLLLLWDLWDWDLDDDWDLWDWWDLWLWLLDLLWLWDWLLWWLLLLLWLLLLLLWLLWLLLLLWLDWLWDLLLLWWWLLDWDLDD"

lds = Counter(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(played, lambda ch: ch in 'W') if k)
for k, g in lds.most_common()[:2]:
    print(f'Length {k} occured {g} time(s)')
```

Prints:

```
Length 1 occured 70 time(s)
Length 2 occured 24 time(s)
```